# Using a device model based Audience to dictate Firebase Remote Config settings

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I want to be able to have different Firebase Remote Config parameter values based upon the device model.

I've set up Firebase Analytics Audiences for each device model using the "Device Model" user property (which is collected automatically [Automatically collected user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en)). It provides a drop down which contains the device models that have already had the app installed on, as shown in the screen shot.
[image: Create Audience]

Then in Remote Config, for the parameter concerned I created a "value for condition", specifying the previously created audience, as shown in the screen shot.
[image: Add new condition]

But having done this, the correct value for a given device model is not retrieved on the device, the device just receives the default value.

Interestingly when I create an Audience based on the user property "User ID", and use this audience to define a value for a remote config parameter it does work correctly.

Based on this I would have suspected the Device Model was not automatically collected, but the fact that device models are shown in the drop down when creating an audience appears to contradict this theory.

What am I doing wrong?

Or is there an alternative way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it doesn't answer the question as to why using the predefined User Property "Device Model" is not working for me. One possible work-around is to define your own User Property and use this in exactly the same way to define audiences based on device model.

Of course in this case it is necessary to explicitly set the User Property on Android, e.g.

```
        firebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("device_model", Build.MODEL);
```

Where "device_model" has been created in Analytics -> User Properties.

I tested this approached and it worked fine.